# How to use a table of search terms in Full Text Search 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

first of all thanks for your time. Now on to the question!,

I am creating a subscription based service for some users. Basically, some users are creating articles(blurbs of information) in one part of their company. Users want to be able to subscribe to words or phrases being used in those articles and get an email if their "subscription phrase is matched". Currently i have a sql server database of all subscriptions made by users. I was thinking of making a stored procedure that takes the "article" text and does a FTS on it. I have a small familiarity with FTS but have no idea how to implement.

In diagrams:

```
Subscriptions:  |Name     |Phrase           |
                |'Josh'   |'Test Text'      |
                |'Jessica'|'Another purpose'|
```

Article coming in: "Test Text is very dangerous" should produce the result `Josh`

A different article  "Test text is very dangerous unless used for another purpose" should produce the result

```
|Josh|
|Jessica|
```

Comment: For your stated objective, why don't you think the "like" keyword is not sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
select * from Subscriptions 
where CHARINDEX(Phrase, 'Test Text is very dangerou') > 0
```